# Combinatorial proof: ${n \choose 1}+6{n \choose 2}+6{n \choose 3} = n^3 $

Tags: combinatorics

Prove $${n \choose 1}+6{n \choose 2}+6{n \choose 3} = n^3$$ without algebra.

I've been trying to think of it in terms of the volume of a cube, and also as the set $\{(x,y,z)|x,y,z \in \mathbb{N}, 1 \leq x,y,z \leq n\}$ *(is this correct syntax?)*, but that's as far as I've gotten.

Comment: Hint: Try to think about $n^3$ as the number of functions $\{1,2,3\} \rightarrow \{1,2, \ldots, n\}$ (or equivalently, the number of words of length $3$ on an $n$-letter alphabet).  Think about the different cases based on how many repetitions you allow.

Comment: Is there a reason we can't just do it?  ${n\choose 1 }= n$ and ${n \choose 2} = \frac {(n(n-1))} 2$ and ${n \choose 3} = \frac {n(n-1)(n-2)}6$ and $n + 3(n(n-1)) + n(n-1)(n-2) = n^3$ ought to be straightforward.

Comment: @fleablood Doesn't matter, OP makes the rules.

Comment: Is the OP saying it's not acceptable?

Comment: @fleablood, math is not necessarily about the goal, but the way ~

Comment: @fleablood The combinatorial proof I can do in my head at a glance.  For your proof I would have to take out a pad of paper.

Comment: Yeah, but the combinatorial proof requires *thinking*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The general case of this formula is
\begin{align*}
   n^k &= \left\{{k \atop 1}\right\}n + \left\{{k \atop 2}\right\} n(n-1) + \dots + \left\{{k \atop k}\right\}n(n-1)(n-2)\dotsb(n-k+1) \\
      &= 1! \left\{{k \atop 1}\right\} \binom{n}{1} + 2! \left\{{k \atop 2}\right\} \binom n2 + \dots + k! \left\{{k \atop k}\right\} \binom nk.
\end{align*}
(To allow for the $k=0$ case we should include a $0! \left\{{k \atop 0}\right\}n^0$ term as well, I guess.)

Here, $\left\{{a \atop b}\right\}$ denotes the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind), which count the number of partitions of an $a$-element set into indistinguishable $b$ subsets. In particular, $b! \left\{{a \atop b}\right\}$ is a very commonly-encountered expression in which we partition an $a$-element set into $b$ *distinguishable* subsets. Equivalently, $b! \left\{{a \atop b}\right\}$ counts the number of surjective functions from $\{1,2,\dots,a\}$ onto $\{1,2,\dots,b\}$.

A word-problem proof of this identity is: if a bar has $n$ brands of beer available, in how many ways can $k$ people order beer? On the one hand, the answer is just $n^k$, because each person can choose a brand independently. On the other hand, we can count the answer in the following way:

- For each value of $i$ between $1$ and $n$, we can consider the case where $i$ different brands actually get ordered.
- We can choose which $i$ brands get ordered in $\binom ni$ ways.
- Once we've fixed the $i$ brands, there are $i! \left\{{k \atop i}\right\}$ surjections from $\{1,2,\dots, k\}$ to $\{1,2,\dots,i\}$: the number of ways for $k$ people to choose from those $i$ brands while ensuring that each brand is picked at least once.
- Finally, we sum over each value of $i$.

---

For the special case of $k=3$, we can count the surjections manually. Here, a minister, a priest, and a rabbi walk into a bar. There are $n$ brands of beer available. In how many ways can all three order beer?

On the one hand, there are clearly $n^3$ ways for them to make independent decisions. On the other hand, we can do casework:

- There are $\binom n1$ ways for all three of them to order the same brand of beer.
- There are $6 \binom n2$ ways for all three of them to order two brands: we choose which two brands in $\binom n2$ ways, choose which brand gets ordered by two people in $2$ ways, and choose which pair of people order the same brand in $3$ ways.
- There are $6 \binom n3$ ways for all three of them to order three different brands: we choose which three brands in $\binom n3$ ways, and match people up to brands of beer in $3! = 6$ ways.

The two ways of counting are equivalent, so $$n^3 = \binom n1 + 6\binom n2 + 6\binom n3.$$

Answer (score 5):

Take the set that you have written, and divide them into three groups based on how many distinct components you have. For example, $\binom{n}{1}$ counts the number of elements of the form $(x,x,x)$. The second term counts elements with two distinct components, and the third counts the elements with three distinct components.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a class with $n$ students, and you hold a spelling bee, a geography bee, and a history bee.  How many different ways can there be winners of the three bees?  On the one hands it's $n\times n\times n=n^3$, since there are $n$ possibilities for each bee.  On the other hand, there are $n\choose1$ ways a single student could win all three bees, $n\choose2$ ways two students could be winners, with $2$ choices for which of those two students wins just one bee and $3$ choices for which bee that student wins, for a total of $6{n\choose2}$ possibilities, and, finally, $n\choose3$ ways the three bees could each be won by a different student, with $3\times2\times1=6$ ways to decide which student won which bee, for a total again of $6{n\choose3}$ possibilities.